# I can't get video working with TV-Out as the only display

Tags: graphics-card, tv, s-video

I have a new [Powercolor HD 4670](http://www.powercolor.com/global/products_features.asp?ProductID=2389) pcie video card with dial DVI and s-video out.

If I connect the s-video output as the only display and power on the PC the display is black & white and scrolls.  Obviously the card isn't outputting the correct signal.

Is the card defective, or is there a setting somewhere?

Could it be a PAL/NTSC issue?  I'm confident that the TV can only accept NTSC inputs.

I should try to get the s-video output working with an LCD attached, but don't have one handy.  I'll borrow one and test that.

I'm running a Gigabyte MA78GM-US2H mobo with a PHenom II 955 processor with Windows 7.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Powercolor and they told me about the PAL/NTSC jumper on the card.  I haven't had to set a jumper in years so it hadn't occurred to me to even look and it doesn't appear to be mentioned in the manual.

There is a jumper on the op edge of the card that, for me at least, shipped in the PAL setting. The driver can override the setting which is why I had it working in windows.  I moved the jumper over and it was clear immediately on boot.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happens when I try to plug my SD TV into the TV-out of my laptop. I can't get it to work, though. It must be some TV format error that I don't have time to deal with.